# Popup Window has a broken image link

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why the image link in my pop up window appears to be broken.  The page I'm working on has a table of links, each one should open a window with an image and description in it.  Can someone tell me where the error might be?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
<!-- 
var imgName; 
function pop(imgName,description) 
{ 
var openWindow=window.open('', 'newwin', 'width=400,height=325,resizable=0,toolbar=0,top=35,left=115'); 
openWindow.document.write('<HTML>') 
openWindow.document.write('<HEAD>') 
openWindow.document.write('<TITLE>&nbsp;</TITLE>') 
openWindow.document.write('</HEAD>') 
openWindow.document.write('<BODY BGCOLOR=#ffffff TOPMARGIN=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 LEFTMARGIN=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 onBlur="window.close()">') 
openWindow.document.write('<CENTER>') 
openWindow.document.write('<A HREF="javascript:window.close()"><IMG SRC="images/parkimages/mapphotos/memorial_mapPhotos/'+imgName+'.jpg" BORDER=0></A><BR>') 
openWindow.document.write(description) 
openWindow.document.write('</CENTER>') 
openWindow.document.write('</BODY>') 
openWindow.document.write('</HTML>') 
} 
// --> 
</SCRIPT> 
<tr> 
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0"> 
<td width="150"><a href="javascript:pop('mlrp_a1','Site A1')"title="Site A1"/>Site A1</a></td>
```

Comment: I might be wrong but as the window you're opening has no url will it not be looking for the image on the users pc?  Is that is the case, just add the domain in from of the image path.

Comment: Agree with @DoctorMick, have you looked at the properties of the image to see what the URL it is attempting to load from?

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a new window in which you are injecting dynamic HTML not sourced from your domain, so therefor it has no root. Your image source is a relative path from your domain, its like you have opened a new page on a different site, you wouldn't expect relative paths to refer to your site. Try using the full URL to the image.